# Angular CLI, linking from one sub component to another

Tags: angular, routes, router

I've created a basic website/app for practicing in CLI.  It provides information about various New World Order conspiracy theories (not a believer myself, just thought it would be fun).  My root component contains a banner and a navbar.  Clicking links on the navbar displays information about a different organization below, using the "" and app-routing-module to display different components.

However, my question is how would I link from within one sub-component to another?  For instance, how could I have a link in the Templar component that direct one to the Free Mason component.

Answer (score 0):

You can Actually Use the selector method to call a Component into the other component, and then automatically the sub-component calling will be implemented.

For Example.
This is my First Component.

```
<p> This Component One 1</p>
```

This is Second Component.

```
 <p>n1 works!</p>
```

And Now I will use the Selector of the Second Component into the HTML of First.

FYI - You will Find your selector in the ts File

```
 <p> This Component One 1</p>
<app-n1></app-n1>
```

The output will be

[image]